# Overlap images on click

Tags: jquery, html, image

I'm trying to create a spot the ball game. Where the user can click on an image to show where abouts they think the ball is. I've got it working, but if you want to click two points which are relatively close to each other you can't as its selecting the previous image..

Is there a way to achieve this, I was thinking about putting a transparent image above them so they aren't selectable but I cant get it to work.

This is what I have so far

http://enjoythespace.com/sites/game/

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good thing to not let them pick them if they are too close together. If you are charging money for each click, I can't imagine somebody intentionally picking two spots that are within only a couple pixels of each other.

However, it might be possible to place a transparent div over the image and place the cross-hair images under it. This worked for me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divSource" style="position:relative;width:500px;">
        <img src="http://chelseavets.org.uk/Gallery/090228vBBC/SpotTheBall.JPG" width="100%" />
        <div id="divTarget" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:solid 1px red;z-index:100;"></div>
    </div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#divTarget').click(function (e) {
            var target = $('<div></div>');
            target.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                backgroundImage: 'url(http://enjoythespace.com/sites/game/img/cross.png)',
                width: '29px',
                height: '27px',
                top: e.offsetY - 14 + 'px',
                left: e.offsetX - 15 + 'px',
                padding: 0,
                margin: 0,
                zIndex: 50
            });
            $('#divSource').append(target);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```